# c# Is there a way to pause a stopwatch when during debug mode a breakpoint is hit and code runs manually line by line?

Tags: c#, debugging

I need a way to pause some stopwatch during debugging, but just when some breakpoint is hit and the code is waiting or working through manually line by line.

This means, we want to pause our stopwatch objects when a breakpoint hit is entered as long as the code is not continuing automatically (F5, stop code debugging and proceed).

Following code shows what we are looking for. For demonstration, breakpoint can be set at line 15 where Console.Writeline("Breakpoint hit"). Please check out the class TimerExample constructor, where we are want to assign some time pausing methods to the debugger, but don't know how.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TimerDebug
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TimeExample TestTimePausingDuringDebug = new TimeExample();
      TestTimePausingDuringDebug.Start();

      Console.WriteLine("Timer Started");
      Console.WriteLine("Breakpoint hit"); // set breakpoint to this line and wait for minimum 15s when breakpoint is hit, then proceed..
      Console.WriteLine("Time should run with more or less 10s from now.");
      while (TestTimePausingDuringDebug._timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000)
      {
        // waiting
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Time passed.");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  public class TimeExample
  {
    public Stopwatch _timer = new Stopwatch();

    public TimeExample()
    {
      // Searching for something like this:
      // Debugger.IsBreakpointHit += StartWait;
      // Debugger.IsContinuing += EndWait; // F5, line by line debugging ended
    }

    public void Start()
    {
      _timer.Restart(); // resets the time
      _timer.Start();
    }      
    private void StartWait(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      _timer.Stop();
    }
    private void EndWait(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      _timer.Start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not possible.  Not showing any code that demonstrates why this matters prevents everybody from proposing an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hans. Unfortunately seems this is really not possible. I researched a lot by lectures and blogs, without any approach to handle such a case. I'm wondering, I think in big platforms where a lot of timesensitive functions are monitored by timers. There must be a lot of devs out there who are also struggling with debugging when such timers cant be handled and paused automatically during a "breakpoint hit"..

Comment: Hi @spaghettiBox, did you ever find a solution for this? In my case I am making some helper methods for debugging large migration processes - and a prediction how long it will still run. As sometimes I want to pause the migration and inspect the state, I don't want this to influence the predicted time left.

Comment: Hi @DirkBoer, surprisingly there is no solution out there to handle such a timer requirement for debugging. As I am working on a large "platform" where I have to handle a lot of timings and supervision topics, I am just wondering that .NET has no approach to handle such timers during debugging in a way. In my case I had to design custom timers which are used according their usecases and can be disabled during debugging through a central enable/disable mechanism which unfortunately we have to set manually when we expect to debug somewhere and stop the program process. Not elegant this approach.

Comment: @spaghettiBox ahh too bad! Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: .NET feature request: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/28974